# AngularJS compare two (scope) arrays and only POST the 'non-same' result (2018)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have two arrays that i like to compare on the ID, if the ID from one array does not exist in the other i will add it with the Http Post.

This is the build up:

```
$scope.Games = [{id:1,Name:"BatMan"},
                {id:2,Name:"SpiderMan"},
                {id:2,Name:"Hulk"}];

$scope.NewGames = [{id:1,Name:"BatMan"},
                   {id:2,Name:"SpiderMan"},
                   {id:3,Name:"Hulk"},
                   {id:4,Name:"DeadPool"},
                   {id:5,Name:"IronMan"}, ,
                   {id:6,Name:"DrStrange"}];
```

so i load all the Games and NewGames with a GET in the two $scopes
Now i would like to compare the two on the id_game, so i was thinking of something like this but can't get it to work, the http section works find however without the indexOf, it will add all the games double in DB if they already existed and that is what i want to prevent.

```
angular.forEach($scope.NewGames, function (value, index) {

  if ($scope.Games.indexOf(value.id ) === -1) {

      console.log('New game to add' + value.Name)         

     $http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'http.....\addGame',
       data: value
     })
  }
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the difference between two arrays in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: the question is the same, but the approach is different in this case, first of all we are 9(!) years further down the line of programming so there should be more efficient ways. As in this case shown by @amrender singh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$scope.Games` is an array of Objects use `findIndex()` instead of `indexOf()`.

The `findIndex()` method executes the function once for each element present in the array:

If it finds an array element where the function returns a true value, findIndex() returns the index of that array element (and does not check the remaining values). If no such element is found it returns -1. In the example given below:

`o` is each object/element  of array `games` and we check for equality between the `id`(o.id) prop for each object of  `games` array with the `findId`. If there is an element in the games array, where the id matches with the `findId`, the condition turns true and `findIndex` returns the index of that element/object.

```js
var games = [{id:1,value:"abc"},{id:2,value:"dfg"},{id:2,value:"fdf"}];
var findId = 2;
// when object with id is present in array
if(games.findIndex((o)=>o.id == findId) > -1);
  console.log("Found");
findId= 6;
//when object with id is not present in array
if(games.findIndex((o)=>o.id == findId) == -1);
  console.log("Not found");
```

Comment: i kinda see where you are going but how would i use this with the if().... ? because there are two array's, the 0.id == 6 in your case also comes from an array, value

Comment: @EwaldBos I have updated my answer please have a look :-)

Comment: @EwaldBos in your case it will be simply equal to : if($scope.Games.findIndex((o)=>o.id_game ===value.id_game ) == -1 )

Comment: nice! works perfect. Just a question, could you perhaps explain how this part works, ... (o) => o.id_game ... and perhaps add it to the answer then i could select is as the right one :)